# Does TestCafe support snapshot testing like Jest?

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm looking for snapshot testing in our project. Does TestCafe support Jest like snapshot testing its a react application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, Snapshot testing support is unavailable.